# How to notify inactive activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, preferences, flags

My program has several activies. When one activity is in the foreground, the user may do something there, and the other inactive (i.e., stopped and paused) activities should be informed so that when they onResume(), they can act upon it accordingly.

My question is: How does the foreground activety enumerate if and what inactive activity exists? And how does it inform them?

I've looked at Intent and Broadcast, they don't seem to be the right answer. I've tried to post an event to the inactive activies' Handler queue, but since I don't know how to enumerate them, so I can't access their handlers either.

Help! Thank you!

(I can't just set a global flag. Because when the first inactive activity becomes activity, it sees it, it clears it. Then the rest of the IA won't know. I can't set a counter flag for everybody to come and decrement one, because I don't know if and how many IA are there. It seems to me that the only way is I get to know who are there and notify them one by one.)

Comment: please use some tags for your questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: How does the foreground activety enumerate if and what inactive activity exists? And how does it inform them?

You don't and you don't.

Think of a Web app, with multiple Web pages. The "foreground Web page" would not "enumerate if and what inactive Web pages exist", let alone "inform them". From the standpoint of the currently-visible Web page, it is the only thing around. The fact that the browser happens to perhaps have other Web pages in its history is immaterial.

The same thing goes with Android activities. One activity should neither know nor care whether there are 0, 1, 2, or 1337 other activities from this application in RAM (though, odds are, it will be well below 1337). Rather, there should be a consistent central data model (e.g., database), and the activities each work against the central data model.

> OK, so does it mean that Android does not support or encourage one activity proactively informs another inactive activity?

Correct.

> So that activies have to poll to get information?

No more or less than Web pages have to poll to get information. That depends a bit on your definition of "poll".

Comment: Great! I think I got what I want, though unexpected. (The difference between web pages and activities is that web pages usually are independent, but activities are collaborative, in a tighter or looser sense. So there are times when they have to talk to each other. But this is immaterial here.) Because this is a simple case, I will just implement a "voice mailbox" for each activity, using Android's Preferenecs or global static or whatever. When one wakes up, he just goes and checks for any voice mails from last night. This should be enough. Thank you!

Comment: @wwyt: "web pages usually are independent, but activities are collaborative" -- IMHO, activities do not "collaborate" any more or less than would separate Web pages of a Web app.

Answer (score 1):

First I doubt that you think in the right way. An activity should ask for information on start up and shouldn't be "informed" by another activity (I don't talk about `startActivityForResult()`).

When you have a lot of data sharing between different activities, you should seriously consider storing them in a configuration class, in `SharedPreferences` or in the database. You main logic problem is what you said:

> I can't just set a global flag. Because when the first inactive activity becomes activity, it sees it, it clears it.

Why ever should an activity clear a flag? It only clears a flag when you tell it to clear it. So thats up to you to stop the activity from clearing your flag.

Comment: _"An activity should ask for information on start up and shouldn't be "informed" by another activity"_ OK, so does it mean that Android does not support or encourage one activity proactively informs another inactive activity? So that activies have to poll to get information? I think so. Android is designed around these new concepts as stopped and paused states, therefore it doesn't seem to make sense to ask Android to provide a way to communicate with those sleeping activies, which were put to sleep for a purpose by Android in the first place. Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using a content provider and calling ContentResolver.notifyChange() to let interested activities know something has changed.

Comment: Thanks, but because this is a very simple notification, content provide can be a little overkill for me. I should have made this clearer in the first place. But thank you very much.